# Why does this code give me error: "Unexpected @ in program"?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (IBAction) createAccount: (id) sender {

NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@”name=%@&password=%@&email=%@”,nameField.text, passwordField.text, emailField.text];

NSString *hostStr = @”domain.tk/in-app/account/create-account.php?”;
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];







if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@”Yes”]){


    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@”Congrats” message:@”Your account has bee succesfully created. “
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@”OK” otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alertsuccess show];
    [alertsuccess release];


} else {
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@”Error” message:@”We are sorry, but an error has been encountered, please try agian later.”
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@”OK” otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertsuccess show];
    [alertsuccess release];

}

}
```

I get the error on almost ever line that has an @, how can I fix this? I (think I) have synthesized all my fields and did IBOutlet in @interface as well as gave them @ property below @interface. I can't figure out how to fix this, what am I missing!

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling as objective c? Does the file have a `.m` file extension?

Comment: Yes, I created it using File>New File>Objective-C Class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing the typographical quotes `”` by regular quotes `"` in your code should help :-)

(This can can happen if you copy/paste code e.g. from PDF documents.)